# use *ngFor on nested JSON array

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to use an expansion panel to hold my data from database so that I can list the data more nicely.

I'm trying to print out my nested JSON array with an *ngFor. Problem is my JSON is nested, how will i manage to do this?

Here I am trying to print out my name and total sales in the top of the panel.
After it is clicked it should then open the underpanel with my other data from the nested array.

**HTML**

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let data of dataList">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{data.name}}
            </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            {{data.total_sales}}
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{data.sales}}
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

**JSON** return by my get.http function

```
{""
    :{"name":null,
    "total_sales":1200,
    "sales": [
    {
         "name":null,
         "masterID":"5049",
         "beerline":"2",
         "containerNo":"1",
         "pluNo":"1",
         "pluName":"Smirnoff 2cl",
         "pluDepartment":"VODKA",
         "pluPrice":"20.00",
         "sold_count":"54"
    }, 
    {
         "name":null,
         "masterID":"4028",
         "beerline":"8",
         "containerNo":"4",
         "pluNo":"1",
         "pluName":"Smirnoff 2cl",
         "pluDepartment":"VODKA",
         "pluPrice":"20.00",
         "sold_count":"1"
    },
    {
         "name":null,
         "masterID":"4028",
         "beerline":"9",
         "containerNo":"5",
         "pluNo":"3",
         "pluName":"Johnsrom",
         "pluDepartment":"rom",
         "pluPrice":"25.00",
         "sold_count":"1"
    },
    {
         "name":null,
         "masterID":"4028",
         "beerline":"10",
         "containerNo":"6",
         "pluNo":"3",
         "pluName":"Johnsrom",
         "pluDepartment":"rom",
         "pluPrice":"25.00",
         "sold_count":"1"
    },
    {
         "name":null,
         "masterID":"4028",
         "beerline":"11",
         "containerNo":"7",
         "pluNo":"3",
         "pluName":"Johnsrom",
         "pluDepartment":"rom",
         "pluPrice":"25.00",
         "sold_count":"1"
    },
    {
         "name":null,
         "masterID":"4028",
         "beerline":"12",
         "containerNo":"8",
         "pluNo":"3",
         "pluName":"Johnsrom",
         "pluDepartment":"rom",
         "pluPrice":"25.00",
         "sold_count":"1"
    }
    ]},
         "Show Room":
    {
         "name":"Show Room",
         "total_sales":4110,

 "sales":[
           {
            "name":"ShowRoom",
            "masterID":"4028",
            "beerline":"1",
            "containerNo":"1",
            "pluNo":"1",
            "pluName":"Smirnoff2cl",
            "pluDepartment":"VODKA",
            "pluPrice":"20.00",
            "sold_count":"198"
           },
           {
            "name":"ShowRoom",
            "masterID":"4028",
            "beerline":"1",
            "containerNo":"2",
            "pluNo":"3",
            "pluName":"Johnsrom",
            "pluDepartment":"rom",
            "pluPrice":"25.00",
            "sold_count":"5"
           },
           {
            "name":"ShowRoom",
            "masterID":"4028",
            "beerline":"3",
            "containerNo":"2",
            "pluNo":"3",
            "pluName":"Johnsrom",
            "pluDepartment":"rom",
            "pluPrice":"25.00",
            "sold_count":"1"
           }
           ]},
           "Henriks Place":
           {
           "name":"Henriks Place",
           "total_sales":50,
              "sales":
                      [
                        {
                         "name":"Henriks Place",
                         "masterID":"4028",
                         "beerline":"4",
                         "containerNo":"2",
                         "pluNo":"3",
                         "pluName":"Johnsrom",
                         "pluDepartment":"rom",
                         "pluPrice":"25.00",
                         "sold_count":"1"
                        },
                        {
                         "name":"Henriks Place",
                         "masterID":"4028",
                         "beerline":"6",
                         "containerNo":"3",
                         "pluNo":"3",
                         "pluName":"Johnsrom",
                         "pluDepartment":"rom",
                         "pluPrice":"25.00",
                         "sold_count":"1"
            }
        ]
     }
}
```

**EDIT:
ERROR I GET:**

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3152)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9253)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10514)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11109)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11069)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SaleComponent.html:33)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10458)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
```

function returning json:

```
getSale1(): Observable<Sale1Model[]> {
        return this.http.get<Sale1Model[]>(API_URL + '/live/sale', this.httpUtils.getHTTPHeader())

    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is my model class:

```
export class Sale1Model {

    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public total_sales: string,
        public sales: string[]) { }
```

Comment: I think the better solution would be change your JSON structure, but could you also show the service that get this?

Comment: @Gabax added error message and my function getting the json, what would you change the json structure to if i was going to do that?

Comment: Could you add **Sale1Model** class too? Anyway I'd change your JSON structure cause you have:
`{ "": { "name": null, "total_sales": 1200, "sales": [ ] }`;
while it would be better something like this:
`{ "name": null, "total_sales": 1200, "sales": [ ] }` or
`{ "data": { "name": null, "total_sales": 1200, "sales": [ ] }`

Comment: @Gabax I have added my model class now. Could it be the way i am trying to state the array in model? - Can you take a look on it? Thank for helping out!

Comment: I don't see errors, but I can't understand why your first object is empty. Anyway you could try one of the answers below and see if it works. I don't know if Angular considers name of empty object, so let me know

Answer (score 1):

use another *ngFor on panel body to iterate nested array

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let data of dataList">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{data.name}}
            </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            {{data.total_sales}}
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div class="sale-body" *ngFor="let s of data.sales"> <sale body here> </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add one more `*ngFor`  loop for nested `sales` array

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let data of dataList">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{data.name}}
            </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            {{data.total_sales}}
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div *ngFor="let sale of data.sales">{{sale.name}}</div> // use your sale object here as you want
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```